# ClassCastException from exact same class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I'm running a database query and trying to cast the result to a Customer object, but I'm getting an error saying:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Entities.Customer cannot be cast to Entities.Customer
```

My code:

```
Customer c = (Customer)em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findByEmail")
        .setParameter("email", user)
        .getSingleResult();
```

I've read that this is due to classloaders, but to be honest it's a bit over my head. Is there a huge issue somewhere else, or am I just casting it incorrectly?

Comment: The class you are trying to cast is probably coming from a different jar. Check again to avoid duplicate entries in the classpath. Things get weird if this happens.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about what this is running on and the context within which the about code is run.

Comment: It's running on a local Glassfish server. Once the user has logged on, I'm trying to get the users details so I can associate some of them with the httpsession.

Comment: You've got two copies of the Entities class, loaded with two different class loaders.  This can only really happen you're using some sort of toolkit that has it's own classpath and class loaders.  Usually you can circumvent the problem by referencing the problem class very early in your app, as it's starting up.  `Class.forName(whatever.path.Entities);` would probably do it.  If that doesn't work you have to remove the class from your classpath and somehow get the (presumably Glassfish) class loader to load it for you.

Comment: I'm not using any toolkits or anything special. How could this have happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have 2 ClassLoaders involved. You can check the classloaders with

```
Customer.class.getClassLoader();

em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findByEmail").setParameter("email", user).getSingleResult().getClass().getClassLoader();
```

Then you can try to find more information.

Comment: It says the classloader is WebappClassLoader. Is that normal?

Comment: Which one? Are both of the WebappClassLoaders? You can use the getParent() method of each classloader to see the whole hierarchy.

Comment: The first one says: WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/).
The second one says: WebappClassLoader (delegate=true)

Comment: Using the getParent() methods I'm getting: org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@51b47feb.

And org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@232e0532

Comment: The first classloader is your webapp's own regular classloader (each webapp gets their own). The second one might be Glassfish's own general one. I don't know how Glassfish handles these, but I've been down the same road with JBoss. You'd need to show how you've laid out your project, do you have an EAR or just a WAR, does your webapp have its own libs and what they are...

Comment: After all that, restarting the server seems to have fixed it! Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Lucky you! Classloading problems can be a b***h.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a choice, I would suggest using JPA 2.0 and use:

```
<T> TypedQuery<T> createNamedQuery(java.lang.String name,
                               java.lang.Class<T> resultClass)
```

I think it should avoid class cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

Like allprog said it is because the class that is being given back to you comes from a different jar than the one of your webapp (I'm assuming you are working on a webapp).

At runtime, your Customer loaded by the class loader from one jar (or your app) is cast into the customer from an other jar (or app).

So different possibilities:

1. either the version of "Customer" are different and the classLoader the same
2. or the two Customers are the same and the classloaders different.

In both cases you get the same error.

you can try to decompile your classes using javap to see what happens.

If you want to know more about classLoading: 
http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/video-do-you-really-get-class-loaders-a-jazoon-talk-by-jevgeni-kabanov/